# while executing android code it sowing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android

showing following error while executing code in android eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at apps.testapp.main(testapp.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.<init>(AbstractVerifier.java:5)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.<init>(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:5)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:124)
    ... 6 more
```

here my code..

```
public class testapp
{
    public static void main(String...arf)
    {
        //File app = new File("appiumAndroid.apk");
        //System.out.println(app.getAbsolutePath());
        //System.out.println(""+test());
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        //capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "5554");
        //capabilities.setCapability("device", "emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.appiaumdemo");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",".MainActivity");
        try
        {           
            RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
            driver.close();

        }  
        catch(MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be compiling against Android, when perhaps you should be building a JavaSE project.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behaviour**, a **specific** problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Android Studio and I had the same problem. I have been using Eclipse up to now. Checking the default Project Settings /Project - Project SDK: showed it was using Android platform for a target.  Switching to Java JDK allowed my Appium script to run.

Comment: I had the same problem and the comment provided the answer so I tried to form an answer.  How would you answer this question so users with this problem can find the answer?